# what is meant by empty rows as feature vectors in text analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, text-processing, feature-extraction

I am doing the movie review sentiment analysis using the data available for Kaggle dataset here using Python. https://www.kaggle.com/c/movie-review-sentiment-analysis-kernels-only/data

I do not have errors here but trying to understand why the rows collecting feature vectors are empty for some cases.

After preprocessing my text such as removing stop words, missing data removal, removing punctuations I tokenize my text into sequences using the following codes.

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=nwords, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n', lower=True,split=' ')
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_train["cleansed_txt"].values)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df_test["cleansed_txt"].values)
X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_train["cleansed_txt"].values)
X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df_test["cleansed_txt"].values)
```

And when I check how does my X_train looks like I find it to be this way. My question is what should I understand from these numbers. Why are some of them empty?

[image]

Comment: @desertnaut It's Keras. Until here only these imports have been useful from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

Comment: Please do not post code in the comments; edit & update your post accordingly, and add the appropriate `keras` tag.